# Finding a representation of an element of Fibonacci sequence using power series.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I need help finding the power series of $f\left(x\right)=\frac{-1}{x^{2}+x-1}$ probably for $x=0$.

I got a sequence defined as $a_{0}=1,\ a_{1}=1\ \ a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 2$. I found out that the radius of convergence of the series $f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ is bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$. Afterwards I found for all $|x|<\frac{1}{2}$ that $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{-1}{x^{2}+x-1}.$$ And now I think I have to find out that the power series of $\frac{-1}{x^{2}+x-1}$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}x^{n}$$ and then I can conclude from the similarities of power series that $a_{n}=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$.

I started by getting to this equality: $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}-\frac{1}{x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right).$$ I wanted to show out that $$\frac{1}{x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}x^{n}, \\ \frac{1}{x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}x^{n},$$ but I can't manage to do that, I tried expanding the Taylor series around $0$ but it's not working for me.

Any hints or help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what a geometric series is?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Yes I do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}=\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{1-x\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}}$$

Now let’s use rationalising/conjugacy technique: $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}=\frac{2(\sqrt{5}+1)}{(\sqrt{5})^2-1^2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$

So you get: $$-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$

Can you proceed with a geometric series?

Two notes: You’ve dropped a minus sign in your factorisation of $f$, and you’ve dropped a power - those two series you ask about should feature $\varphi^{n\color{red}{+1}}x^n$.

Comment: Thank you man! I managed to solve it with your help.

Comment: @Abzikro You’re welcome. Do note however that you need to make changes to the series you get, as I mentioned, with $\varphi^{n+1}$ rather than $\varphi^n$. There is also an issue where the most common convention for $F_n$ is $F_0=0,F_1=1$ rather than $F_0=1,F_1=1$. This is why the series you are expecting is not actually the same as the series that you get.

Comment: You are right, I came to the conclusion at the end that $a_{n}=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$. Which is true checking the first elements. the series they defined in my homework was a1=1, a2=1 and so on, and the power series started with n=1, but i found it impossible to find out that  $f\left(x\right)=\frac{-1}{x^{2}+x-1}$. So I rearranged the series to start from 0.